# Run jupyter notebook within virtualenvwrapper

Tags: virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to set up an environment for multiple jupyter notebooks. I made a virtual environment installed a module a need (pandas) but jupyter notebook returns

`ModuleNoteFoundError: No module named pandas`

while within the environment I ran

`pip3 list`

and my output was

```
numpy           1.17.4 
pandas          0.25.3 
pip             19.3.1 
python-dateutil 2.8.1  
pytz            2019.3 
setuptools      41.6.0 
six             1.13.0 
wheel           0.33.6
```

finally, I printed the version of Python being ran in jupyter and got
`3.7.5rc1` so it looks to me like jupyter isn't within my environment and I'm not sure how to go about doing it with `virtualenvwrapper`

Answer (score 0):

Although not absolutely necessary, using *sudo* mode for the installation makes the packages available across all users in the system (especially ones with a lower privilege). Again, there are pros & cons for the approach and I've had similar conflicts that prompted me use sudo *mode* for packages that are intended for use in multiple projects.

You seem to have package versions that should work in unison; must be some access permission issue.